# jquery addClass() to first position of multiple classes

Tags: jquery

what it does:

```
<p class="foo"></p>
$('p').addClass('bar');
```

output:

```
<p class="foo bar"></p>
```

what i need:

```
<p class="bar foo"></p>
```

So is it possible to add a class to an element to the first position?

edit (context): theres a split function on the last class right now. if another class is added its appended to the second split array as well.

Comment: why do you need that? give some context...

Comment: I am not sure and I don't know if it's a good practice if you just remove `foo`, then add `bar` and add again `foo`

Comment: @algorhythm Um because the order dictates which style's values override the other. In this case if both `foo` and `bar` indicated a `font-size` the first one would take precedence.

Comment: @thatidiotguy overriding order where?  If you mean CSS that's based on the order they're defined, not applied.

Comment: You could add bar to the parent element. Then foo would override it.

Comment: @ExplosionPills You mean in the stylesheet? really, i had no idea that was the case. I guess I have just gotten lucky O.O

Comment: Why you need a method for this? you can try `(..).prop('class', 'firstClazz')` and just concat your next class to get `(..).prop('class', 'secondClazz firstClazz')`

Comment: @algorhythm read mine, I explained you and didn't use any method to achieve that :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function prependClass(sel, strClass) {
    var $el = jQuery(sel);

    /* prepend class */
    var classes = $el.attr('class');
    classes = strClass +' ' +classes;
    $el.attr('class', classes);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you can use `class` as variable? I think its a reserved word.

Comment: @OscarJara I changed it at same time ;)

Answer (score 17):

```
 (function($) {

    jQuery.fn.extend({
        prependClass: function(newClasses) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var currentClasses = $(this).prop("class");
                $(this).removeClass(currentClasses).addClass(newClasses + " " + currentClasses);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It properly ensures the class is not added twice, and creates a nice little jQuery function.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way to do it.

```
$('#foo').attr('class', 'new-class ' + $('#foo').attr('class'));
```

Comment: This is the best option as it takes the original class list and adds your necessary, new class name then adds it at the beginning. Nice work, John!

Answer (score 3):

This should not be a dependency for you in any way at all because of the limited control you have over the `className` string, but you can do this:

```
$("p").removeClass('foo').addClass('bar foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this, live demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/eZe4b/

```
$('p').prop('class', 'bar foo');
```

Otherwise you will need to play around with `addClass` and `removeClass` to get `bar foo` result in that order.

---

By the other hand, I don't get at all your question but if you just want to add `bar foo` class to the first `p` element just do this:

`$('p').eq(0).prop('class', 'bar foo');`

Comment: what is if you add further classes to the orig. DOM-element. Then they will be deleted...

Comment: @algorhythm you can try `$(..).prop('class', 'firstClazz')` and just concat your next class to get `$(..).prop('class', 'secondClazz firstClazz')` and if there is other one then `$(..).prop('class', 'thirdClazz secondClazz firstClazz')` what matters is the string that you pass as the second argument in the `.prop()` method

Comment: Right, and then you have my solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a **no-hack** solution for this:

```js
$(".product").each(function(i, el) {
  var cList = [];

  $.each(this.classList, function(index, val) {
    cList.push(val);
  })

  this.classList.remove(...cList);

  cList.unshift("first-class");

  this.classList.add(...cList);

  // here it is
  console.log(this.classList);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="product type-product status-publish">a</li>
  <li class="product type-product status-publish">b</li>
  <li class="product type-product status-publish">c</li>
</ul>
```