# How Do I implement a jQuery prepend function for class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get a function to prepend a name to my defined class.

The function is:

```
(function($) {

    jQuery.fn.extend({
        prependClass: function(newClasses) {
            return this.each(function() {
                var currentClasses = $(this).prop("class");
                $(this).removeClass(currentClasses).addClass(newClasses + " " + currentClasses);
            });
        }
    });

})(jQuery);
```

This was taken from this link: [jquery addClass() to first position of multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14461853/jquery-addclass-to-first-position-of-multiple-classes/23839395)

I have a link like this:

```
<a class="half first3547" href="#">this</a>
```

I want it to become:

```
<a class="paid first3547" href="#">this</a>
```

I'm using this:

```
$("#mycontent a.half").removeClass("half").addClass("paid");
```

But that appends the class.  It becomes this:

```
<a class="first3547 paid " href="#">this</a>
```

I don't understand how to implement the function so that it works with my code.  I tried placing it above my script, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why do you need that exact order of class names?

Comment: @jmargolisvt Some interesting use cases here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15672815/5561605

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$("#mycontent a.half").removeClass('half').prependClass('paid');`

```js
(function($) {

  jQuery.fn.extend({
    prependClass: function(newClasses) {
      return this.each(function() {
        var currentClasses = $(this).prop("class");
        $(this).removeClass(currentClasses).addClass(newClasses + " " + currentClasses);
      });
    }
  });

})(jQuery);

$("#mycontent a.half").removeClass('half').prependClass('paid');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycontent">
  <a class="half first3547" href="#">this</a>
</div>
```