# jquery removeClass this type of class [class^=notice-]

Tags: jquery, css

This html is generated, and prepended to a form, with jquery when an ajax request is `done`:

```
<div class="notice-success clickable close" id="notice"><p class="icon">response message</p></div>
```

the class `notice-success` can also be:
`notice-error`,
`notice-warning`,
`notice-info`
depending on the situation or response.

Here's a simplified portion of my javascript:

```
let $form = $('form#'+$(this).attr('id'));  //  use this specific form
let $formNotice = $form.find('#notice');  //  locate #notice element (if any)

if($formNotice.length){  //  if there's a #notice, then update it to reflect the new response.
    $formNotice.removeClass('[class^=notice-]');  //  <-- this doesn't work
    $formNotice.addClass('notice-'+data['type'])
    $formNotice.html('<p class="icon">'+data['msg']+'</p>');
} else {
    $('<div class="notice-'+data['type']+' clickable close" id="notice"><p class="icon">'+data['msg']+'</p></div>').hide().prependTo($form).slideDown("slow");
}
```

`.removeClass('[class^=notice-]')` does not work.
removing one of the other classes (`clickable` or `close`) works just fine.
`$formNotice.addClass` and `$formNotice.html` is also ok.

So my question would then be how to change/remove any of the `notice-`-classes?

I also tried `$formNotice.removeClass('class');` to just remove all classes, and then put them all back with `.addClass()`. But that didn't work either.. I just got a whole lot of classes added when resubmitting the form over and over...

Any suggestion?

**EDIT (solved):**
By using this code allowed me to find and remove a class that starts width `notice-` (in my case).
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608620/1355562
Thanks for pointing me in the right direcion...

Then, when adding a new `notice-?`-class with `.addClass`, it got added at the end - Which somehow broke the code. All css-properties besides `background-color` didn't get rendered correctly.
After some testing it turned out this class had to be the first.
By knowing this, i had to find a way to add this class at the beginning of the class list. So I found this:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839395/1355562

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608587/how-to-remove-a-class-that-starts-with

Comment: Add double quotes around notice- (here: removeClass('[class^=notice-]');)

Comment: You can use regex

Comment: Try the `*=` selector instead of `^=`. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Hey @Martin. Did not work unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
$formNotice.removeClass('notice-error notice-warning notice-info');
```

Comment: It's not what he asked for

Comment: It could work, but if one decides to expand, or change, the list of possible `notice-types`, then one would also need to update this code. I don't think that would be a good enought solution.. but thanks for your suggestion anyway :)